# IOS How do I use a button send a message?

Tags: ios, button

I set a button, it  jump to make a phone  call view while be clicked!Now I set another button send a message while  be clicked. How to make it just stay in APP view rather than jump to the phone send message view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phone calls cannot be made from within an app.  You can only redirect the user using a telephone number URL.

Comment: THX!Whether to call or send a message , can not be make from within an APP ?

Comment: The idea with iOS 4 and up is that by default, apps are encouraged to resume where they left off.  This makes switching back and forth between apps like the Telephone app and your app pain-free for your users.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible without delving into private frameworks.